# Create different version of a website in WIX based on different location

Tags: domains, web-hosting, subdirectory, wix

I am new to wix. I have a website. It's connected to a domain `example.com`. Now I want to create diffrent version of this website and connect it to a subdirectory `example.com/usa`. Can I do that in wix? I am hosting my website on WIX. And I bought that domain from GoDaddy.

I create a copy of my website and I want to connect to a subdirectory of my main domain. I am not finding any option to do that.

Comment: If you can't find an option to use a subdirectory, I would consider trying a subdomain. In general, it's easier to get subdomains working with setups like this than it is to get subdirectories working.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I know it's easy. But I want to be sure that is it possible to make this in subdirectory in WIX

Comment: If you can make something like example.com/contact, then using the same technique, you should be able to do what you want.